# How do I make X11 windows play nice with the Dock on OS X?

Tags: macos, xorg, dock

My dock is on the left side of my screen & by default X11 Window Manager (wants to start at the uppermost left corner & it's always behind the dock.  The X11 terminal app itself doesn't do this, but some of the programs I use have a default grey background (I believe like TWM), and these always start in the uppermost left corner behind the dock.

Comment: Have you tried the current XQuartz version as replacement for bundled X11?

Comment: Yes, but it is a TWM problem, which comes bundled with XQuartz in case there are no other window managers to use.